# Method returns different values when using hardcoded string as parameter and when using variable with that value

Tags: javascript, tinymce

This:

```
str = "test                 test"
ed.selection.setContent(str);//1
```

Behaves differently than this:

```
ed.selection.setContent("test                 test");//2
```

I'm working with a text editor, and setContent sets the value in the textbox.
1 sets the value in the textbox to

```
"test test"
```

and 2 sets it to

```
"test                 test".
```

I can only use variables in the program, not hardcoded values. What should I do? Why does this happen?

Comment: There should be zero difference between those two lines. You using tabs in one and spaces in the other?

Comment: @epascarello No. But I execute 1 from code, and 2 from Chrome console.

Comment: And what happens when you execute 1 from the console?

Comment: @epascarello It removes the spaces :(

Comment: So the problem is not with the two lines, it is when the code executes.

Comment: @epascarello No, the problem lies in the two lines. When both are executed from console, 1 removes the spaces, and 2 doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using tinyMCE? (Please retag your question)
[Their DOCs specificy](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent):

> this will cleanup the content before it gets set using the different
>   cleanup rules options

Try adding: `{format : 'raw'}` after the string, like so:

```
ed.selection.setContent("test                 test", {format : 'raw'});
```

On both accounts, and see if it helps.

Edit (final, I hope):
use `str = str.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');` before inserting it to the function.
You can test it [here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/), this should work.

Comment: You should try my new solution. (Edited answer again)

Answer (score 1):

No, it will make no difference. If the behaviour is really anomalous, the assignment to the global variable `str` messes up with the rest of your code. Make them local by adding the `var` keyword.

Comment: Also don't forget `;` after the `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that inserting several spaces at once (not per keyboard) will let the browser display them as one single space.

If a user enters spaces there will be some spaces entered as protected spaces to trick the browser behaviour. When inserting content unsing the setContent method you will need to replace each second space with a protected space in order to get the same look.

Comment: Can i get more details? Hpw do you mean 'replace each second space with a protected space'?

Comment: have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Table_of_spaces. a protected space is a no-break-space with character code 160